# How to normalise dissimilarity and exposure indices (for longitudinal data)

Tags: r, panel-data, similarities, social-science

I'm currently working with longitudinal data and I wanted to compare school and residential segregation (natives vs minorities) over time and across specific territorial sub-units (NUTS 3 level).
The idea is to compute dissimilarity (D) and exposure (E) indices in each territorial unit using schools as obs. But I've noticed that the number of schools per territorial units are not fixed over time. It might have happened that some schools have been closed or merged with others.
Since the number of schools are not fixed, this might bias my results since "there is less space to move". Therefore, I wanted to ask you if there are methods to compute the D and E indices in a "normalised" way so to take into consideration the non-fixed $n$ of schools over time.

Comment: Are *schools* the unit of analysis or do you have students within schools? Regardless, hierarchical modeling would be one approach with schools nested within geography. Great intro is Singer's paper *Using SAS PROC MIXED to Fit Multilevel Models*, useful for any software, not just SAS. Also her book *Applied Longitudinal Data Analysis* and Gelman and Hill's book *Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/ Hierarchical Models*